# OpenGL with Gtk+, shapes are not being drawn despite background being cleared

Tags: c++, c, opengl, gtk

I am trying to get OpenGL to work with gtk+.  It seemed to be working size I was able to clear the background color.  However, when I went to draw something it is not there.  Am I missing something.  I put the eye at 10, 10, 10 and I am looking at the origin.  I should see a back triangle near the origin.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <iostream>

GtkWidget* wnd;
GtkWidget* glarea;

static gboolean render(GtkGLArea *area, GdkGLContext *context)
{
    int w = gtk_widget_get_allocated_width(GTK_WIDGET(area));
    int h = gtk_widget_get_allocated_height(GTK_WIDGET(area));
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(180, (double)w / (double)h, 0.1, 100.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);

    glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glColor3f(0, 0, 0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(-1, 2, -1);
    glVertex3f(1, 3, 2);
    glEnd();

    return TRUE;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    wnd = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    glarea = gtk_gl_area_new();

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(wnd), glarea);
    g_signal_connect(wnd, "destroy", gtk_main_quit, 0);

    g_signal_connect(glarea, "render", G_CALLBACK(render), NULL);

    gtk_widget_show_all(wnd);
    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why a 180 degree FOV instead of something like 60 or 90?

Comment: I had it at 60 originally.  I opened it up to see if I could find the shape.  Had the same issue with 60

Comment: Your [core drawing code in a GLUT MCVE (with the FOV fix)](http://pastebin.com/qaDRT4Cy) seems to [work fine](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fIusx.png) on my system.

Comment: Not a GTK guy but you might need to flush/swapbuffers somehow to force the update to the screen.  Maybe toss a `glFlush()` down before the `return TRUE`.

Comment: ...`gtk_gl_area_swap_buffers()`?

Comment: I tried it.  That function is not under the same gtk.h header as GtkGlArea   `error: ‘gtk_gl_area_swap_buffers’ was not declared in this scope`

Comment: To me it seems that you are sending your vertices in CW order, have you tried sending them in CCW order? You should be able to do this by swapping the last two `glVertex3f` calls. Alas I cannot test this hypothesis as setting up the GTK env is too much of burden for me right now. If this happen to be the problem you may want to look into [Face Culling](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Face_Culling).

Comment: Shouldn't your eye be at `0, 0, 10`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source: [Emanuele Bassi's blog - GTK+ developer](https://www.bassi.io/articles/2015/02/17/using-opengl-with-gtk/)

> [...] The OpenGL support inside GTK+ requires core GL profiles, and thus it won’t work with the fixed pipeline API that was common until OpenGL 3.2 and later versions. this means that you won’t be able to use API like glRotatef(), or glBegin()/glEnd() pairs, or any of that stuff.

Solution: drop the fixed function pipeline.